# php list file in directory with links issue

Tags: php

I am getting a list of files in the directory however when I click on the hyperlink it is routing me to the root directory.

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('mydownloads');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
   if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
       $link = "<a href='$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
       echo $link;
   }
 }

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Comment: _"it is routing me to the root directory"_ <- what is _"it"_? How is _it_ routing you; what does the network traffic look like (hint: use your browser's _Network_ console and select the _"Preserve log"_ option)?

Comment: You need to append the directory's variable to the filename and add a separator. Do that, and if it works, you can post your own answer; Stack supports it.

Comment: This will link to the server folders, not a url (in the href). You need to use something like str_replace to change root folder names to your servers url.